# pdf not added to email in objective-c in IOS 5

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I am trying to add an email as an attachment to my mail. I do it like this.

```
-(IBAction)mailPDF:(id)sender{
    MFMailComposeViewController* controller = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    controller.mailComposeDelegate = self;
    NSLog(@"myData is %@",myData);
    [controller setSubject:@"Geselecteerde favorieten van Genk on Stage"];
    [controller setMessageBody:@"<p>Hallo muziekliefhebber <br /> In bijlage vind je jouw favorieten. Volg en praat met ons mee op facebook.com/genkonstage of @genkonstage!<br /> Veel plezier op Genk on stage! </p>" isHTML:YES];
    if (controller){
        [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
        [controller addAttachmentData:myData mimeType:@"application/pdf" fileName:@"favorite.pdf"];
    }else{
        NSLog(@"nothing to show");
    }
}
```

This is how I set myData

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *filePath = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"favorite.pdf"];
 myData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile: filePath];
```

When I look at my log `myData` (which is my pdf) it is NOT empty. Also when I browse in the finder to my documents folder of the `simulator` I see that I have a PDF.

Can someone tell me why my pdf is not added to my mail ?

thank you!

**EDIT**
It seems that above code only works in IOS6. So the question is now. Why is it not working in IOS 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are presenting the view controller first, and then attaching the file. Change the sequence of actions:

That is, In your lines of code:

```
[self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];

[controller addAttachmentData:myData mimeType:@"application/pdf" fileName:@"favorite.pdf"];
```

Modify them as:

```
[controller addAttachmentData:myData mimeType:@"application/pdf" fileName:@"favorite.pdf"];

[self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

Hope it will resolve the issue :)

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
-(IBAction)mailPDF:(id)sender{
  MFMailComposeViewController* controller = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
  controller.mailComposeDelegate = self;
  NSLog(@"myData is %@",myData);
  [controller setSubject:@"Geselecteerde favorieten van Genk on Stage"];
  [controller setMessageBody:@"<p>Hallo muziekliefhebber <br /> In bijlage vind je jouw favorieten. Volg en praat met ons mee op facebook.com/genkonstage of @genkonstage!<br /> Veel plezier op Genk on stage! </p>" isHTML:YES];

  if (controller)
     {
     NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
     NSString *filePath = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"favorite.pdf"];
     NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
     [controller addAttachmentData:myData mimeType:@"application/pdf" fileName:@"favorite.pdf"];
     [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
    }
 else{
    NSLog(@"nothing to show");
    }
}
```